# ESXi esxcli Error: Unknown command or namespace vm process kill –t=soft –w=67909

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm running ESXi 6.5 embedded host client. When i ssh into the system I can run `esxcli vm process list` and get the expected output:

```
testserver1
   World ID: 67909
   Process ID: 0
   VMX Cartel ID: 67908
   UUID: someuuid
   Display Name: testserver1
   Config File: /vmfs/volumes/somelocation/testserver1/testserver1.vmx
```

But if i run `esxcli vm process kill –t=soft –w=67909` I get the error `Error: Unknown command or namespace vm process kill –t=soft –w=67909`

To confirm i'm running the correct command, i ran `esxcli vm process kill -help` and get

```
Error: Invalid option -h

Usage: esxcli vm process kill [cmd options]

Description: 
  kill                  Used to forcibly kill Virtual Machines that are stuck and not responding to normal stop operations.

Cmd options:
  -t|--type=<str>       The type of kill operation to attempt. There are three types of VM kills that can be attempted:   [soft, hard, force]. Users should always
                        attempt 'soft' kills first, which will give the VMX process a chance to shutdown cleanly (like kill or kill -SIGTERM). If that does not work
                        move to 'hard' kills which will shutdown the process immediately (like kill -9 or kill -SIGKILL). 'force' should be used as a last resort
                        attempt to kill the VM. If all three fail then a reboot is required. (required)
  -w|--world-id=<long>  The World ID of the Virtual Machine to kill. This can be obtained from the 'vm process list' command (required)
```

Can you see anything i'm doing wrong that might be preventing this command from working?
I realize there's `vim-cmd` alternative [in docs](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1004340) but i'm trying to figure out why the first option from the docs is responding like it's not even a valid command.

Comment: Have you tried the long cmd options, i.e. --type and --world instead of -t and -w? ;)

Comment: yes like `esxcli vm process kill –-type=soft –-world-id=67909` and similar variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With esxcli commands you use either the short options WITHOUT the equal sign (e.g. `esxcli vm process kill -t soft -w 67909`) or the long options WITH the equal sign (`esxcli vm process kill –-type=soft –-world-id=67909`).

Comment: i think `esxcli` commands must not be well tested with the vmware team or the docs need an overhaul. `esxcli vm process kill –-type=soft –-world-id=67909` does not work and returns the same error. However `esxcli vm process kill -t soft -w 67909` works.